# Regex matched the link with only one sub folder and requested content is JavaScript file

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex matching the links have only one sub folder with the requested content is JavaScript files with the length of 7 characters or more and no `?` and `&` character in the back of the file.

Some specific examples:

```
(1) https://some.domain.example.tld/randomcharacter/randomfilename.js // match
(2) https://some.domain.example.tld/randomcharacter/randomfilename.js? // not match
(3) https://some.domain.example.tld/randomcharacter/randomfilename.js?a=b&c=d // not match
(4) https://some.domain.example.tld/subdir/public/lib/randomcharacter/randomfilename.js // not match
```

P/s: Please understand `tld`, `randomcharacter` and `randomfilename` are non-fixed.

This is my current regex:

```
/\/[a-zA-Z]{7,}\/[a-zA-Z]{7,}\.js$(?!(\?|&))/
```

It is correct for cases (1), (2) and (3). In the case (4), although there are a few other paths in front, it still matches and I don't want that!
[image]

How do I make it match exactly as I want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to include the first '//' to guarantee that you will have only 1 subfolder like:

```
\/\/[a-zA-Z.]+\/[a-zA-Z]{7,}\/[a-zA-Z]{7,}\.js$
```

And you don't need the (?!(?|&)) after the end of the line '$' since there is nothing if the '$' matches